# VNC send Ctrl+Alt+F1-F6 to server

Tags: virtual-machine, vnc

I've been trying to figure this out now for a while, I'm connecting to virtual machines through VNC, and by default you get a graphical or ncurses interface, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> takes you to a console with debug information. However, Gentoo intercepts these commands.

How can I pass them through to the VNC server?

Edit: Some more details the VNC is being ran on the VM host, thus it just captures display output from the VM and sends any keys to the VM as if it's an actual keyboard connected to it. Hence I can switch to the TTY's if my <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> keystrokes were getting through (Works fine when on Windows for example).

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are trying to do. 

As I understand it, you want to send CTRL-ALT-F3 to the remote machine in order to see its console, but this won't work - VNC does not redirect console output.

Comment: @RenanBirckPinheiro Added clarification

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105295/what-numeric-key-codes-do-i-need-to-send-for-the-magic-sysrq-functionality-in-a

Answer (score 8):

**The proper solution:** get a VNC client that can send those keys. Like [jsbillings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3976/jsbillings) says, some clients give you the option of sending keys to the remote via a menu. With the standard `xvnc4viewer`, you can use the `-MenuKey` option to set the key that activates the menu. Again, as per [jsbillings'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3976/jsbillings) 
answer, the default key is <kbd>F8</kbd>.

**The hack:** if you have a shell running on the remote server, try `chvt 3` (or `sudo chvt 3`). On the console, you don't need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> repeatedly) to go back to the X server's TTY. Or just log in and say `sudo chvt 7; logout` (or whatever the X VT is).

**The stupid kludge:** since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> is captured early by the X server, the direct (and hard) way is to disable (temporarily or permanently) these keys. This requires you to modify your X configuration and is an annoying thing to do, and probably a bad idea besides. Go with one of the others. :)

Comment: If interested in modifying the X config, see e.g.: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1530826#p1530826

Comment: The stupid kludge isn't that stupid actually. The X server will stop capturing Ctrl+Alt+F# with only one command: `setxkbmap -option srvrkeys:none`

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can use <kbd>F8</kbd> to bring up a menu, which should allow you to click <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> before you hit <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Comment: This is only true for TigerVNC (standard in Red Hat/Fedora) but not for TightVNC (Debian/Ubuntu).

Answer (score 3):

Use TigerVNC.

With TigerVNC (a variation of TightVNC) you can lock the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> modifier keys via the menu. To open the menu press the <kbd>F8</kbd> key.

Answer (score -1):

Tried with tigervnc-viewer on Ubuntu but the <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> locks did not seem effective. In the end resorted to xvnc4viewer which has the same option and then it did work.

Comment: Please, *format* your answers by using Markdown in order to get them readable, like the answer above!