# How to access agetty terminals (e.g. TTY2, 3, 4, etc.) from QEMU VM

Tags: freebsd, keyboard-shortcuts, qemu, agetty

In my QEMU virtual machine (started with `qemu-kvm -boot d arch-freebsd.img -m 4096`) I'd like to access an agetty terminal, which I'd normally access with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>F3</kbd> if I need tty3, <kbd>F4</kbd> if tty4, *etc.*), unfortunately pressing these keys just merely changes me to an agetty terminal on my host (as opposed to the guest system I'm trying to go to tty2 in). If this were a VirtualBox VM I'd press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (specifically the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in the centre of my keyboard, i.e. my right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key) to access tty2, but this doesn't work with QEMU. If you suggest I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to get the VM to grab all my keyboard and mouse inputs, then pressing the keys to access the agetty terminals I've tried doing that and it doesn't work.

EDIT: The proposed duplicate link doesn't list what solved my problem, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd>. I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> that seems to be suggested there (although I'm having trouble getting my head around what it's about as what VNC is, is a mystery to me), that's kind of the problem here.

Comment: What about the TTY you're on? Is it running agetty?

Comment: I believe so. Does FreeBSD do so by default? If so yes. If not, no. I've tried this with Linux VMs too, with the same problem.

Comment: Then, assuming (a) it's showing a login prompt and (b) you can login, and (c) you can run commands as root, the `chvt` command could be used.

Comment: Also, for the TTYS, Alt-Fx (without the Ctrl) might also work.

Comment: Hey you're right it works! Write up an answer to this effect, that Alt-Fx works, and I'll accept it!

Comment: Potential answerers may be interested in https://askubuntu.com/questions/54814/ .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VNC send Ctrl+Alt+F1-F6 to server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34283/vnc-send-ctrlaltf1-f6-to-server)

Comment: Almost wrote an answer... Never mind though, I found a post that listed available options.

Comment: It's generic VNC answers, muru, and doesn't list the QEMU monitor commands given in AskUbuntu.  It is not `agetty` in FreeBSD, by the way BH2017.  And the only `chvt` command on FreeBSD to my knowledge is the one that I wrote.

Comment: The same issue also occurs under Linux as I said JdeBP. Just tested with a PCLinuxOS live session QEMU VM and Alt-Fx didn't go to an agetty terminal.

Comment: @JdeBP I also tried the AskUbuntu solution and it didn't work as after following it I'm seeing a black screen in the QEMU session.

Comment: From the dupe's accepted: "On the console, you don't need Ctrl+Alt+F#, you can use Alt+F#". The other options - `chvt` and Alt+arrow-keys are also given in it.

Comment: Ah OK. The PCLinuxOS live session doesn't seem to like running `chvt 2` as root (sudo isn't pre-insalled on PCLinuxOS) as it gives me a blank, black screen, no login prompt. Alt-arrow key doesn't work either.

Comment: The question that you have flagged as a duplicate, muru, does not actually have an accepted answer, and as I said does not list the QEMU monitor commands.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to access an `agetty` terminal, which I'd normally access with <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

There are two errors in that, one of which points to an answer, one of several possible answers.

The first error is that FreeBSD *does not have* Wietse Venema's `agetty` ("alternative getty").  It has ordinary BSD `getty`.  So that nomenclature is wrong.  Indeed, there is not necessarily a `getty` running on every kernel virtual terminal, that depending from what is configured in `/etc/ttys`.

The second error is that one normally accesses the *multiple kernel virtual terminals* with just plain <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> and a function key on FreeBSD.  The <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd> is superfluous, and only necessary when an X server is in the foreground.  X servers only recognize chords that have both <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>, but the keyboard mappings given to kernel itself, which is what handles this when an X server is not in the foreground, only actually require <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>, just as they did on SCO Multiscreen (where this originated):

```
% sed -n -e '1,4p;/ 068 /p' /usr/share/vt/keymaps/uk.kbd
# $FreeBSD$
#                                                         alt
# scan                       cntrl          alt    alt   cntrl lock
# code  base   shift  cntrl  shift  alt    shift  cntrl  shift state
  068   fkey10 fkey22 fkey34 fkey46 scr10  scr10  scr10  scr10   O
%
```

Of course, one *can* send a <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> chord to the guest operating system, and there are two ways of doing this:

- Turn on sticky keys in the guest.  Use sticky keys to stick the <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd> modifier down, and then press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.  Sticky keys support is a GUI thing, note.  This will not help if a GUI session is not in the foreground.
- Switch to the QEMU Monitor Console, and use the `sendkey` command.  That can send a wide range of chords to the guest operating system.  In this particular case it would be `sendkey ctrl-alt-f2`.  Then switch *back from* the monitor console, of course.

Ubuntu users, including muru here, have suggested the `chvt` command.  That's Linux-think.  There is no `chvt` command in FreeBSD.  I wrote one, and provide it in the nosh toolset; but the operating system does not come with one out of the box.

My `chvt` is primarily for use with user-space virtual terminals, and defaults to `head0`, but it can handle the kernel virtual terminals as well.  One would for this purpose invoke it (assuming that one has the privileges to access `/dev/ttyv0`) as:

```
chvt 1@ttyv0
```

The tool supplied out of the box is `vidcontrol`, which for this particular task one would invoke (assuming that one has the privileges to access `/dev/ttyv0`) as:

```
vidcontrol -s 2 < /dev/ttyv0
```

## Further reading

- "[Monitor](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor)". *QEMU*. Wikibooks.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`chvt`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/chvt.html). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Soren Schmidt, Sascha Wildner, et al. (2016-01-19). [`vidcontrol`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vidcontrol&format=html) *FreeBSD General Commands Manual*.  freebsd.org.
- [What is the difference between getty and agetty?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255385/)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480705/5132

Comment: I noticed you missed the fact that sendkey ctrl-alt-f2 isn't working for PCLinuxOS, a Linux distro, I just get a black screen (no line cursor, no login prompt, nothing). I thought I mentioned it in the comments above, but apparently not. I tried it from the supposed duplicate answer and I experience this issue.

Comment: I didn't miss it.  Read carefully.  (-:

Comment: > switch back from the monitor console

What the ... does that mean? I ignored it as I didn't get what it meant. Ctrl-Alt-2 (what got me there) doesn't switch me back.